# How to share a ZIO Queue between ZIO Tasks via the ZIO Environment

Tags: scala, zio

I'm somewhat new to Scala and ZIO and have run into something of an odd puzzle.

I would like to setup a ZIO Environment containing a ZIO Queue and later
have different ZIO Tasks `offer` and `take` from this shared Queue.

I tried defining my environment like this

```scala
    trait MainEnv extends Console with Clock
    {
      val mainQueue = Queue.unbounded[String]
    }
```

and accessing the queue from separate tasks like this

```scala
    for {
      env      <- ZIO.environment[MainEnv]
      queue    <- env.mainQueue
      ...
```

but in my test I observe each of my separate tasks is given a separate Queue instance.
Looking at the signature for [`unbounded`](https://github.com/zio/zio/blob/master/core/shared/src/main/scala/zio/Queue.scala#L392)

```
  def unbounded[A]: UIO[Queue[A]]
```

I observe it doesn't immediately return a Queue but rather returns an effect which returns
a queue so while the observed behavior makes sense it isn't at all what I was hoping for and
I don't see a clear way to get the behavior I would like.

Would appreciate any suggestions as to how to achieve my goal of setting up different
tasks communicating via a shared queue stored in the Environment.

---

For reference here is my code and output.

#### sample execution

```
bash-3.2$ sbt run
[info] Loading project definition from /private/tmp/env-q/project
[info] Loading settings for project root from build.sbt ...
[info] Set current project to example (in build file:/private/tmp/env-q/)
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /private/tmp/env-q/target/scala-2.12/classes ...
[info] Done compiling.
[info] Packaging /private/tmp/env-q/target/scala-2.12/example_2.12-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Running example.Main 
env example.Main$$anon$1@36fbcafd queue zio.Queue$$anon$1@65b9a444
env example.Main$$anon$1@36fbcafd queue zio.Queue$$anon$1@7c050764
```

(hangs here - notice env object is the same but queue objects are different so second task is stuck)

#### /tmp/env-q/test.scala

Here is my complete test which is based on example from slide 37 of https://www.slideshare.net/jdegoes/zio-queue

```scala
    package example
    import zio.{App, Queue, ZIO}
    import zio.blocking.Blocking
    import zio.clock.Clock
    import zio.console._

    trait MainEnv extends Console with Clock    // environment with queue
    {
      val mainQueue = Queue.unbounded[String]
    }

    object Main extends App                     // main test
    {
      val task1 = for {                         // task to add something to the queue
        env      <- ZIO.environment[MainEnv]
        queue    <- env.mainQueue
        _        <- putStrLn(s"env $env queue $queue")
        _        <- queue.offer("Give me Coffee!")
      } yield ()

      val task2 = for {                         // task to remove+print stuff from queue
        env      <- ZIO.environment[MainEnv]
        queue    <- env.mainQueue
        _        <- putStrLn(s"env $env queue $queue")
        _        <- queue.take.flatMap(putStrLn)
      } yield ()

      val program = ZIO.runtime[MainEnv]        // top level to run both tasks
        .flatMap {
          implicit rts =>
            for {
              _ <- task1.fork
              _ <- task2
            } yield ()
        }

      val runEnv = new MainEnv with Console.Live with Clock.Live

      def run(args: List[String]) =
        program.provide(runEnv).fold(_ => 1, _ => 0)
    }
```

#### /tmp/env-q/build.sbt

Here is the build.sbt I used

```
val ZioVersion = "1.0.0-RC13"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    organization := "example",
    name := "example",
    version := "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT",
    scalaVersion := "2.12.8",
    scalacOptions ++= Seq("-Ypartial-unification"),
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "dev.zio"                 %% "zio"                 % ZioVersion,
    ),
    addCompilerPlugin("org.spire-math" %% "kind-projector"     % "0.9.6"),
    addCompilerPlugin("com.olegpy"     %% "better-monadic-for" % "0.2.4")
  )

scalacOptions ++= Seq(
  "-deprecation",               // Emit warning and location for usages of deprecated APIs.
  "-encoding", "UTF-8",         // Specify character encoding used by source files.
  "-language:higherKinds",      // Allow higher-kinded types
  "-language:postfixOps",       // Allows operator syntax in postfix position (deprecated since Scala 2.10)
  "-feature",                   // Emit warning and location for usages of features that should be imported explicitly.
  "-Ypartial-unification",      // Enable partial unification in type constructor inference
  "-Xfatal-warnings",           // Fail the compilation if there are any warnings
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the [Official Gitter Channel](https://gitter.im/ZIO/Core?at=5d934fef462ada51232ddaed) for ZIO Core, Adam Fraser suggested

> You would want to have you environment just have a `Queue[String]` and then you would want to use a method like `provideM` with `Queue.unbounded` to create one queue and provide it to your whole application.  That's where `provideM` as opposed to `provide` comes in. It let's you satisfy an environment that requires an `A` by providing a `ZIO[A]`.

A little digging into the ZIO source revealed a helpful example in [DefaultTestReporterSpec.scala](https://github.com/zio/zio/blob/86b56cab469e7604664c9fa7c1208c6209afc034/test/shared/src/test/scala/zio/test/DefaultTestReporterSpec.scala#L153-L159).

By defining the Environment as

```scala
  trait MainEnv extends Console with Clock    // environment with queue
  {
    val mainQueue: Queue[String]
  }
```

changing my tasks to access `env.mainQueue` with `=` instead of `<-` (because mainQueue is a `Queue[String]` now and not a `UIO[Queue[String]]`, removing `runEnv` and changing the `run` method in my test to use `provideSomeM`

```
  def run(args: List[String]) =
    program.provideSomeM(
      for {
        q <- Queue.unbounded[String]
      } yield new MainEnv with Console.Live with Clock.Live {
        override val mainQueue = q
      }
    ).fold(_ => 1, _ => 0)
```

I was able to get the intended result:

```
sbt:example> run
[info] Running example.Main 
env example.Main$$anon$1@45bfc0da queue zio.Queue$$anon$1@13b73d56
env example.Main$$anon$1@45bfc0da queue zio.Queue$$anon$1@13b73d56
Give me Coffee!
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed Oct 1, 2019 7:41:47 AM
```